Data Relationship mapping SPRING JPA empty
I am facing problem :
i have a book class and a category class which has many to many relationship.When i call JpaRepository to get all books but i receive a empty list categories

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    private String author;

    @NotNull
    private int yearPublished;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private Set<Category> categories;
}




@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}


Please can you help me! thank you!

Can you show the repository method / query you are using for getting the books? Have you tried to activate the sql statement logging, check if the generated query matches with your needs and test if running this directly on db, it returns some records?

i used findAll() from extend JpaRepository:
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
List findByCategories_IdIn(List categoryIds);
}
public List getAllBooks() {
List books = bookRepository.findAll();
return bookMapper.toResponseDtoList(books);
}

Also check what you are inserting in your model. This setup requires that when books are saved, they have categories referenced in the categories set. Turn on SQL logging and see what is inserted and what SQL is used for the select calls - and verify the data in the database directly.
